# Получение имени авторизованного пользователя в Django

Tags: django

Как получить имя авторизованного на сайте пользователя для выборки по его логину записей из БД? Я так понял, что надо переписать метод **get_queryset** для изменения запроса, и в нем прописать исправленный вопрос.

```
class LinksView(ListView):
    model = Links
    template_name = 'users/links.html'
    context_object_name = 'links'

    def get_queryset(self): 
        username = request.user.username
        return Links.objects.filter(user=username)
```

Но получить имя у меня никак не получается.

Может, вообще другой способ использовать?

Comment: Почему выборка нужна именно по логину, а не по id?

Comment: Можно и по id, почему нет. Как к нему обратиться?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class LinksView(ListView):
    model = Links
    template_name = 'users/links.html'
    context_object_name = 'links'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Links.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
```